# Rxjs init resource once with hot observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, system.reactive

I have a service setup with this code below :

```
@Injectable()
export class StaticResourcesService {

private resourcesTree$: Observable<any>;

getSpecificLabel(resourceName: string, type: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.getResources().map(resources => {
      return jp.value(resources, `$.${resourceName}[?(@.type=="${type}")].label`);
    });
  }

private getResources(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.resourcesTree$ != null) {
      return this.resourcesTree$;
    }
    let source = this.getResourcesFilePath() // get obs<string> with a file path
      .mergeMap(path => {
        console.log(`static-resources path: ${path}`);
        return this.http.get(path).map(res => res.json()); // get json obj
      }).do(res => {
        this.resourcesTree$ = Observable.of(res);
      });
    return source;
  }
```

a custom angular pipe with a transform method like this :

```
transform(resourceType: string, resourceName: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.staticResourcesService.getSpecificLabel(resourceName, resourceType);
  }
```

and I use this custom pipe in a simple html page:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item?.status | staticResource:'MY_RES' | async }}</div>
```

When I load the page for the first time, the custom pipe will process 4 times (the ngFor loops 4x) and will never get its source data from resourcesTree$. I understand that its a normal behavior as the subscriptions will listen at the same time and the do will be performed 4x. But what I want is an optimized way with accessing the data only one time and then take advantage of resourcesTree$ the next 3 times. I tried to makes it "hot" by using the share() method on the source. But I can't make it work properly.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this please ? Maybe Im all wrong and Im really open to any suggestions here.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure its possible? Because in `getSpecificLabel` you are basically creating 4 totally different observables. `share()` wouldn't help you here. I think it could be achievable by making 'map observable' pipe but it depends what `jp.value()` does.

Comment: jp.value is not very relevant here, it only helps me to retrieve a specific label into my json object using jsonpath

Comment: Your observable has side effect - that could be a sign you are doing something wrong. I think using this approach its not possible. Can you please describe what exactly you are trying to achieve? It should display JSON file from URL based by `item.status` field?

Comment: Yes I have a json object :
"MISSION_TYPE": [
    {
      "type": "PRODUCT_DELIVERY",
      "label": "Livraison produit"
    },
    {
      "type": "MANUAL_PRODUCT_DELIVERY",
      "label": "Livraison produit manuelle"
    },
    {
      "type": "OTHER__DELIVERY",
      "label": "Livraison autre"
    }
  ]

and I would like to get the label for each code. But I want only one access to the json file and then get the values from memory using my resourcesTree$ variable.

Comment: And you want to download that JSON when given status appears. But when the JSON was already downloaded in the past use the cached value?

Comment: yes exactly, I want only one access and then cached value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern for an async service is to make the shared resource a Subject() or ReplaySubject(). That way, you just hook up subscribers and they wait nicely for data to arrive.

In your example, it's slicing up the resource, so that's a map operator (as you have already). Also some way to signal the fetch has ***started*** (don't care if it's finished yet, since it's observable).

Since getResources() is no longer subscribed externally, you'll need to replace .do() with .subscribe().

```
@Injectable()
export class StaticResourcesService {

private resourcesTree$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
private status = 'unloaded';

getSpecificLabel(resourceName: string, type: string): Observable<string> {
  if( this.status === 'unloaded') {
    this.status = 'loading';
    getResources();   
  }
  return resourcesTree$.map(resources => {
    return jp.value(resources, `$.${resourceName}[?(@.type=="${type}")].label`);
  });
}

private getResources(): Observable<any> {
  this.getResourcesFilePath() // get obs<string> with a file path
    .mergeMap(path => {
      console.log(`static-resources path: ${path}`);
      return this.http.get(path).map(res => res.json()); // get json obj
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.resourcesTree$.next(res);
        this.status = 'loaded';
      });
  }
```